# Upload directory in php

Tags: php, forms, upload

I have the following code that seems to work with my form but.....
the script uploads to a folder named temp and not in the folder "image".
How do i tell this script to upload to the chosen folder?.

```
 if($_POST){
    //include database connection
    include '../../libs/db_connect.php';

       try{
                 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["image"]["error"] . "<br />";
else
{
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["image"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["image"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["image"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `move_uploaded_file` ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)) function, to move the file to specific directory.

By default PHP stores the uploaded image in a temporary directory.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
$target_dir = 'your directory'
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);

/*enter conditions for check if upload is Ok here (file size, same names, etc), use $_FILES for comparations */

if ($uploadOK == true)
{ if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'], $target_file))
  { echo 'Success!';
    echo /*all you need to echo out, you can use $target_file for info about your file*/;
  }
}
```